# Checking whether path is a file or directory

Tags: c

I just started learning C and am trying to do path listing. I have tried to list the path in the directory using `dirent` and tried to check if the result is a file or directory, using `stat`. However, even if the path is a file, it will return every path as a directory.

This is my code:
[Edit]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <dirent.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        DIR *mydir = opendir("/Library/Logs");
        char path[250];
        struct dirent *entry = NULL;
        struct stat buf;

        while((entry = readdir(mydir))) /* If we get EOF, the expression is 0 and
                                         * the loop stops. */
        {
            snprintf(path, 250, "%s",entry->d_name);
            stat(path,&buf);
            if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode))
                printf("D: %s\n", path);
            else if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))
                printf("F: %s\n", path);
            else
                printf("O: %s\n", path);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you checked whether `stat()` succeeded, you'd find that it fails every time unless you are in `/Library/Logs` as the working directory.  And you can't analyze the returned data from a failed system call sensibly; there is nothing you can say about the information in `buf` except that it looks like a directory entry (but that's purely by accident).  See [Joe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/57135/joe)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20625123/15168) for a succinct summary of what you else you need to do. But checking the result of every system call is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stat(entry->d_name,&buf);
```

At this point, you don't have any context about the directory you're looking in.

You will need to create a buffer, and concatenate your `directory`/`filename` before calling `stat` (using `strcat` or `snprintf`)

Checking the call to `stat`'s return value -- if non-zero, look at `errno` to see what went wrong.  I'm guessing it's currently reporting an ENOENT.

Comment: Hi am new to c so pardon me if I get anything wrong. So what I can try is to create a char buffer [250] and strcat to conctenate the path before calling stat function?

Comment: Yes, though it might be easier to use snprintf (using `%s/%s` as the format).

Comment: OK will try it out later. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you help to take a look at my edit? i tried to do as what u have mentioned but im still getting the same results. is there anything wrong?

Comment: Close.  But (at least)  you need to combine dir and filename: `snprintf(path, 250, "%s/%s","/Library/Logs",entry->d_name);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using **readdir** and **dirent**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
/* "readdir" etc. are defined here. */
#include <dirent.h>
/* limits.h defines "PATH_MAX". */
#include <limits.h>

/* List the files in "dir_name". */

static void
list_dir (const char * dir_name)
{
    DIR * d;

    /* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */

    d = opendir (dir_name);

    /* Check it was opened. */
    if (! d) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1) {
        struct dirent * entry;
        const char * d_name;

        /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
        entry = readdir (d);
        if (! entry) {
            /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
               out of the while loop. */
            break;
        }
        d_name = entry->d_name;
        /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
        printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);

        /* See if "entry" is a subdirectory of "d". */

        if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {

            /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */

            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 &&
                strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];

                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                        "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
                printf ("%s\n", path);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
                list_dir (path);
            }
        }
    }
    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    list_dir ("/Library/Logs");
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
/Library/Logs/.<br />
/Library/Logs/..<br />
/Library/Logs/somedir001<br />
/Library/Logs/somedir002
```

Comment: Hi i have tried using yours and i like the fact that it is recursive(that is what I am planning to do) . However when i reach a file path that starts with ./, it will return me a permission denied error and stops the whole program

Comment: The `d_type` member of `struct dirent` is not present on all systems (it's not required by POSIX), and on those where it is present, it's not always supported on all file systems.  So it's recommended to use `stat(2)` on each directory entry unless you know for sure that your OS and file system support the `d_type` member.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Hi, I kinda understand what you are saying but if I would like this code to implement stat(2) as what u mentioned, how can it be done? I have no clue how to use it. Sorry for my poor understanding of the language